# How to change all bullets label color of chart in amcharts

Tags: amcharts

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TqjzV.png)

```
var chart = am4core.create("all_realtime", am4charts.XYChart);
                            chart.data = chartdata;
                            // Create axes
                            var dateAxis = chart.xAxes.push(new am4charts.DateAxis());
                            dateAxis.dataFields.category = "commonReqDt";
                            dateAxis.title.text = "TIME";
                            dateAxis.title.fill = am4core.color("#aab8c5");
                            dateAxis.renderer.labels.template.fill = am4core.color("#fff");

                            var valueAxis = chart.yAxes.push(new am4charts.ValueAxis());
                            valueAxis.renderer.labels.template.fill = am4core.color("#aab8c5");
                            valueAxis.renderer.baseGrid.stroke = am4core.color("#454e5b");
                            valueAxis.renderer.grid.template.stroke = am4core.color("#454e5b");
                            valueAxis.renderer.grid.template.strokeWidth = 1;
                            valueAxis.renderer.grid.template.strokeOpacity = 0.8;
                            valueAxis.title.text = "SCORE";
                            valueAxis.title.fill = am4core.color("#aab8c5");
                            valueAxis.max = 1;

function createSeries(field, name, tooltip, color) {
                                var series = chart.series.push(new am4charts.XYSeries());
                                series.dataFields.valueY = field;
                                series.dataFields.dateX = "commonReqDt";
                                series.name = name;
                                var bullet = series.bullets.push(new am4charts.LabelBullet());
                                bullet.label.text = name;
                                bullet.label.fill = am4core.color(color);
                                bullet.tooltipText = "aaaa"
                                bullet.tooltip = new am4core.Tooltip();
                                bullet.tooltip.getFillFromObject = false;
                                bullet.tooltip.label.fill = am4core.color("#fff");
                                bullet.tooltip.background.fill = am4core.color("#664cfd");
                                bullet.events.on("hit", function(event){
                                    //click Event

                                    //this working
                                    event.target.label.fill = am4core.color("green");

                                     //this not working
                                    bullet.label.fill = am4core.color("green");         
                                });
                               return series;
                            }

                            createSeries("100", "O", "OK", "#fff");
```

hi, I'm beginner user.
I want change all bullets, but only know change one a bullet.
when click a bullet, How to change all the bullet label color of chart in amcharts.
help me please

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change all bullets when you click on anyone. Don't target the one you clicked, try like this:

```
bullet.events.on("hit", function(event){
    //click Event
    //set ALL bullets
    bullet.label.fill = am4core.color("green");
});
```

-- Normally to change bullet color and borders

```
var bullet = series.bullets.push(new am4charts.LabelBullet());
bullet.fill = am4core.color("#000"); // fill bullets with black
bullet.stroke = am4core.color("#000"); // bullets' borders in black
```

doc for labelbullet: https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v4/reference/labelbullet/

Comment: thanks for your answer.
but I have already tried this code ->'bullet.label.fill = ...'.
not working..

Comment: i tried bullet.events.on("hit", function(event){
    //click Event
    //set ALL bullets
    bullet.label.fill = am4core.color("green");
}); 
not working.

Comment: I understood but did you try: bullet.fill, take off "label" ?

Comment: yes. i tried.
not error. just not working

Comment: Share on jsfiddle.net please. I cannot help more without seeing.

Comment: I modified my code. please see one more . i write all code

Comment: Sorry I cannot help without seeing. Please make a jsfiddle and I'll check it.

Comment: Furthermore, in your edit you let "label".

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/skdi0517/zuLynvdt/20/


I'm late because I've never tried jsfidlle 

I made it anyway. please help

Answer (score 0):

Use a CircleBullet instead of a LabelBullet. A LabelBullet is meant for text, and using an "O" character as a makeshift bullet isn't really optimal. If you still want an empty circle that gets filled, just adjust the bullet's `fill` and `stroke` to your liking:

```
    // start with empty/white filled circle
    var bullet = series.bullets.push(new am4charts.CircleBullet());
    bullet.fill = am4core.color("#fff");
    bullet.stroke = color;
    // ...
    // fill in every bullet on click
    bullet.events.on("hit", function(event) {
       bullet.fill = am4core.color("red");         
    });
```

Updated fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/aq9xd7r1/